# real analytic inverse function theorem

Tags: holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions, inverse-function-theorem

I have a two part question about real analyticity and whether I have a an error in reasoning.
Suppose I have a multivariate holomorphic mapping $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, with $f(U \cap \mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ would $f|_{U \cap \mathbb{R}^n}$ then be real analytic?

My thinking is, that I can show, that all the coefficients in the power series expansion must be real because I can calculate the limit of the difference quotients over the real numbers. I have seen such an argument in the univariate case in a different post but am not sure whether there are intricacies in the multivariate case.

If this is correct would the inverse/implicit function theorem for real analytic mappings directly follow from the version for holomorphic mappings?
I.e. for the inverse function theorem and a real analytic mapping $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with regular $df(z)$, $z \in U$, take the complex candidate of $f^{-1}$ but how can one show, that $f^{-1}$ is real on the real numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: Composition of analytic functions are analytic so it is obvious that $F(z) = f(z,0,\ldots)$  is analytic. If $a \in \mathbb{R} \cap U,F'(a) \ne 0$ then locally for $r$ small enough and $|s-F(a)| < \sup_{|u-a|=r} |F(u)-F(a)|$ then $F^{-1}(s) = \frac{1}{2i\pi } \int_{|u-a| = r} \frac{u F'(u)}{F(u)-s}du$ is analytic, and its restriction to $(a-r,a+r)$ is real analytic

Comment: thank you reuns! But this just inverts the function restricted to one of the axes? Also my question was why is the restriction to the real plane analytic (i.e why are the coefficients of the power series real) in the multivariate case

Comment: $f^{-1}$ has to be real on the real numbers otherwise $f^{-1} \circ f(U \cap \mathbb{R}) \neq U \cap \mathbb{R}$ contradicting the assumption that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$.